# Selective hardware upgrade

Tags: discrimination, hardware

Is it justified for a company to upgrade the hardware for some people and refuse for other?

In my work, screen real estate is really important. I have been noticing some of my colleagues with these bigger screens for some time now. But when I ordered the bigger screen, my manager refused and the reason given was that the higher management had decided that they now only order the new screen for a new employee, or if your current screen is faulty or really old. My current screens work fine, but I guess a bigger screen with more real estate to work on will increase my productivity and efficiency. What's bothering me is that why are some people given a better tool than other? To be honest it is not a big issue, but it is still bothering me

Do you think it would be wise to escalate this issue?

Edit: Would just like to add that its not as if this is a purely cosmetic upgrade. A bigger screen real estate is quite useful in our work. Can I do without it, yes sure, but so can other people who got the upgrade. Is that my ego speaking, maybe. I think one important detail that I failed to convey in my original post is that initially the screen was available to anyone who ordered it. The colleagues that I am talking about who got the new one did not have a faulty screen. It was only when I ordered, I was told that the policy has been changed, and from now on, only faulty screen will be replaced.

Comment: it's stupid of the company, but there isn't much you can do if upper management has decided not to provide that equipment.

Comment: Are you sure your current screen isn't faulty?

Comment: @PeterM on a completely unrelated anecdote. When my spouse wanted a bigger TV, ours suddenly got damaged during a move. Funny how that works huh?

Comment: Do you have to constantly scroll through your applications with your current screen?

Comment: @SolarMike I think the increase in productivity has already been [proven](https://gbr.pepperdine.edu/2010/08/three-ways-larger-monitors-can-improve-productivity/)

Comment: @PeterM is that the OP or someone else?

Comment: As other colleagues are getting bigger screens, maybe ask for one (or two) of their old ones, and go for a multi-monitor setup.

Comment: "Do you think it would be wise to escalate this issue?" - Your management has made it crystal clear, money for new monitors is finite, you won't be getting a new monitor until a replacement is needed

Comment: A well-massaged ego can improve productivity. A new screen easily pays for itself quickly because happy employees tend to do more work.

Comment: @gnasher729 if hardware given of "ego massaging" purposes (vs. some simple strict policy) than it would not be possible to answer this question as we would never know on which side of "worth to improve productivity" the OP is :)

Comment: @SolarMike  The company made these bigger screens available in the first place because they know they increase productivity. They initially planned to replace the screens for all the employees, irrespective of weather the current screens are old or not. One a few people had ordered and got the screens, they changed the policy. Even now some people are getting new screens, the managers get them ordered for newly hired employees and then give them to their own team members.

Comment: @aakalim - It’s your company’s proactive to hand out new monitors or set the priority of whom will receive one.  You have asked for one which has been denied by your manager .

Comment: So why can’t your manager order for a "new employee" and then give it to you? If the other managers are capable of doing it…

Answer (score 7):

> What's bothering me is that why are some people given a better tool than other?

You have been told exactly why some people get a new screen. Let it go. You’ll get one in time.

Comment: People who got the new screen initially did not get it because the previous one was broken or really old. This policy was implemented after they realized that the cost of replacing the screens for all the employees would be prohibitive. But anyway I should let it go.

Answer (score 4):

Do not escalate the issue as it sounds like it would be a bad idea.
Try however talking to some of the people who have these large multi monitor setups and see how they managed to get them.

If they're being given new monitors you could maybe claim their old ones?
Or perhaps ask around and just see if there are any "extra" monitors laying around?

At the end of the day all you can do is ask nicely :)
It's not what you know, but who you know.

Comment: I understand it would be a bad idea. My idea of escalating the issue was to ask my manager once again if there is anyway i can get the monitor since i can see that some of my collogues also have the upgraded hardware. I have talked to my collogues who have these setups and they got them very easily by ordering and their old screens were perfectly fine. That's why i ordered one but by that time the company had changed the policy. But i understand i should probably let it go.

Comment: @aakalim - How recently did you make the request, beating a dead horse a week after you have asked and been denied, won’t put you in a good situation. I probably deny the request, just out of principle, if I had denied a request and had someone make the same request.